# 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Index was outside the bounds of the array

Every time I try to record data in, for instance, 2 Farms and 1 Bull I get this error... I think it may have something to do with the `ReDim`.

Whenever there is more farms then there are bulls I have this error ... however if it's 1 farm it can take as many bulls.

```
    Private Farm() As FarmInfo
    Private Farms, Bulls, Weekends As Integer

    Private Structure FarmInfo
        Public FarmName As String
        Public FarmSize As Double
        Public Bull() As BullInfo
        Public LowestIncomeB As Double
        Public FarmRating As Double
    End Structure

    Private Structure BullInfo
        Public Income() As Integer
        Public AverageIncome As Double
    End Structure

    Private Sub DisplayGrid(ByVal R As Integer, 'subroutine with parameters
     ByVal C As Integer,
     ByVal T As String)

        grdOutput.Row = R 'row setting
        grdOutput.Col = C 'col setting
        grdOutput.Text = T 'printing

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmInkunziBreeding_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        grdOutput.DebugState = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInput.Click
        Dim nLoop As Integer

        Farms = CInt(InputBox("Enter in how many farms there are"))
        Bulls = CInt(InputBox("Enter in how many Bulls there are in total"))
        Weekends = CInt(InputBox("Enter in how many Weekends the bulls have been rented for"))

        ReDim Farm(Farms)


        For nLoop = 1 To Farms
            ReDim Farm(nLoop).Bull(Bulls)
        Next

        For nLoop = 1 To Farms
            ReDim Farm(nLoop).Bull(nLoop).Income(Weekends)
        Next

        Labels()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Labels()
        Dim nLoop As Integer

        grdOutput.Rows = Weekends + 6
        grdOutput.Cols = Farms + 1

        For nLoop = 1 To Farms
            DisplayGrid(0, nLoop, "Farm" & CStr(nLoop))
        Next

        DisplayGrid(1, 0, "Farm Name:")
        DisplayGrid(2, 0, "Farm Size:")

        For nLoop = 1 To Weekends
            DisplayGrid(nLoop + 2, 0, "Weekend " & CStr(nLoop) & ":")
        Next

        DisplayGrid(nLoop + 2, 0, "AverageIncome:")
        DisplayGrid(nLoop + 3, 0, "Lowest Income Bull:")
        DisplayGrid(nLoop + 4, 0, "Farm Rating:")


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Consider using a `List` generic instead of arrays.

Comment: Also consider using a Class rather than Structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ReDim` statements should be structured as:

```
    Dim nLoopBulls As Integer

    ReDim Farm(Farms)

    For nLoop = 1 To Farms
        ReDim Farm(nLoop).Bull(Bulls)
        For nLoopBulls = 1 To Bulls
            ReDim Farm(nLoop).Bull(nLoopBulls).Income(Weekends)
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Its the same number of bulls for each farm

Comment: @ProgrammerJunkie - OK - I saw the question saying `"Enter in how many Bulls there are in total"` and thought that might be obtaining the total across **all** farms.  But if it is the total in one farm, and all the others have the same number (very egalitarian!), then what you are doing makes sense.